# How can I render view of another action in the controller? I use Kohana 3.0.11

Tags: model-view-controller, kohana, kohana-3

I need use the same view for three different actions in controller. How can I render one view for all of actions? I googled but found nothing useful... And important is I use Kohana 3.0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's bad in creating the view in each action?

```
action_1()
{
   $view = View::factory('something');
   // rest of code
}
action_2()
{
   $view = View::factory('something');
   // rest of code
}
action_3()
{
   $view = View::factory('something');
   // rest of code
}
```

Alternatively you can store the view in your base controller in before action and access it in the child controller:

```
class Controller_Base
{
   protected $_view;

   public function before()
   {
      $this->_view = View::factory('something');
   }
}

class Controller_Yours exnteds Controller_Base
{
   public function action_1()
   {
      // use $this->_view to get it
   }

   public function action_2()
   {
      // use $this->_view to get it
   }

   public function action_3()
   {
      // use $this->_view to get it
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method and return the view

```
...
private function myView($param1, $param2=NULL) {
    return View::factory('myView')
        ->bind('param1', $param1)
        ->bind('param2', $param2);
}

public function action_view1() {
    return $this->myView('param1');
}

public function action_view2() {
    return $this->myView('param1', 'param2');
}
```